# Setting a variable to the containing method's name

Tags: c#

This should seem pretty simple, but I'm having a time visualizing it. Lets say I have a method:

```
public Person person(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    //code and such

    string methodName = "Person person";
}
```

Is there a way to create a variable and set it to the method's name dynamically? I am needing this so when I call a custom exception method, I can set the offending method's name for logging. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reflection is the way to go.

Comment: Is there are a reason you need this?

Comment: Do you need return type space name, or just method name?

Comment: I edited my post with a better explanation. I basically need the name as a string for error logging purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

If you want the type too, you can use:

```
var method = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
var methodName = string.Format("{0} {1}", method.DeclaringType.Name, method.Name);
```

**Edit:** Now that I see you're writing a logging function, you may want to try something like this from MSDN docs:

```
public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}
```

The `[CallerMemberName]` attribute indicates that the compiler should pass in the calling function. This makes it faster than using reflection. Check out this link for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is there a difference between: `System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name` and the answer you supplied?

Comment: No, it's a static method so the type you call it on doesn't really matter... either way it's calling it from MethodBase.

Comment: I went with your answer because the error handler has already been written for me and I'm just tightening up the code, so this works well. That being said, you also provided some other useful bits of code I can incorporate elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

```
string methodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution if using .NET 4.5 is using the [`CallerMemberName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.

```
public class Example
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Bar();
    }

    private void Bar([CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(caller); //Writes "Foo"
    }
}
```

It does not give you the name of the function you are in but the name of the function who called you. I don't know if this will be useful for your exception handler, but it can be very useful for implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
private string _exampleProperty;

public String ExampleProperty
{
    get { return _exampleProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _exampleProperty) return;
        _exampleProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) 
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: Yea I didn't mention that initially because they asked for the **current** method's name. But I agree this is better for logging purposes.